# Why code in r about generation of Gamma random variables does not return the expected output?

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, simulation, gamma-distribution

I have the following algorithm

1. Generate U~(0,1)
2. X=-beta*ln(u_1*u_2*...*u_alpha)
3. repeat step 1 an step 2 N times

I think in r is as follows

```
Gam<-function(alpha,beta){
N<-1000
u<-runif(alpha)
x<-rep(0,alpha)
X<-rep(0,N)

for(j in 1:N){
for(i in 1:alpha){
x[i]<--beta*log(prod(u[i]))
X[j]<-x[i]
}
}
return(X)}

#Comparation with the predefined gamma function

y<-rgamma(alpha,beta)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

hist(X,freq=F,nclass=10)
hist(y,freq=F,nclass=10)
```

> The output is 1000 times the same number .2139196 when I call the function with alpha=3 and beta=4

At least there is no error but it should have not return the same number,

what am I doing  wrong in the current code?

Comment: A few obvious things... `prod(u[i])` just gives `u[i]` which is a single value.  You probably want `prod(u)` - and don't need the `i` loop.  You are also only generating one set of random `u` variables - you might want to do that inside the loop to get a different set each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Andrew Gustar's comment, here is the code you want:

```
Gam <- function(alpha, beta){
  N <- 1000
  X <- rep(0,N)
  for(j in 1:N){
    u <- runif(alpha)
    X[j] <- -beta * log(prod(u))
  }
  return(X)
}
```

Moreover, this code samples the Gamma distribution with shape parameter `alpha` and **scale** parameter `beta`, while `beta` in `rgamma(N, alpha, beta)` is the **rate** parameter. So, to compare with `rgamma` you have to do:

```
alpha <- 3; beta <- 4
y1 <- Gam(alpha, beta)
y2 <- rgamma(1000, alpha, scale=beta)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(y1, freq=F, nclass=10)
hist(y2, freq=F, nclass=10)
```

or

```
y2 <- rgamma(1000, alpha, 1/beta)
```

(the rate is the inverse of the scale).